# Spring - Hibernate Multitenancy Issue

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, spring-mvc, multi-tenant

I am trying to implement the multitenancy SCHEMA approach (Separate schema for each tenant) for my SAAS product, I tried to Autowire datasource bean in my MultiTenantConnectionProviderImpl, but its giving me null pointer exception. Below is my code.

Spring Conf File :-

```
<bean id="dataSource" class="org.apache.commons.dbcp.BasicDataSource"
    destroy-method="close" p:driverClassName="${app.jdbc.driverClassName}"
    p:url="${app.jdbc.databaseurl}" p:username="${app.jdbc.username}"
    p:password="${app.jdbc.password}"/>

<bean id="sessionFactory"
    class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.LocalSessionFactoryBean">
    <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource" />
    <property name="configLocation">
        <value>classpath:hibernate.applicationDB.cfg.xml</value>
    </property>
    <property name="hibernateProperties">
        <props>
            <prop key="hibernate.dialect">${app.jdbc.dialect}</prop>
            <prop key="hibernate.show_sql">true</prop>
            <prop key="hibernate.connection.autoReconnect">true</prop>
            <prop key="connection.autoReconnectForPools">true</prop>
            <prop key="connection.is-connection-validation-required">true</prop>
            <prop key="hibernate.c3p0.minPoolSize">5</prop>
            <prop key="hibernate.c3p0.maxPoolSize">100</prop>
            <prop key="hibernate.c3p0.timeout">1800</prop>
            <prop key="hibernate.c3p0.max_statement">55</prop>
            <prop key="hibernate.c3p0.idle_test_period">2000</prop>
            <prop key="hibernate.c3p0.numHelperThreads">20</prop>
            <prop key="hibernate.multiTenancy">SCHEMA</prop>
            <prop key="hibernate.tenant_identifier_resolver">com.elecnor.ecosystem.hibernate.CurrentTenantIdentifierResolverImpl</prop>
            <prop key="hibernate.multi_tenant_connection_provider">com.elecnor.ecosystem.hibernate.MultiTenantConnectionProviderImpl</prop>
        </props>
    </property>
</bean>

<bean id="currentTenantIdentifierResolverImpl"
      class="com.elecnor.ecosystem.hibernate.CurrentTenantIdentifierResolverImpl" scope="request">
    <aop:scoped-proxy/>
</bean>

<bean id="multiTenantConnectionProviderImpl" class="com.elecnor.ecosystem.hibernate.MultiTenantConnectionProviderImpl">
    <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource"/>
</bean>
```

MultiTenantConnectionProviderImpl Code :-

```
@Component
public class MultiTenantConnectionProviderImpl implements MultiTenantConnectionProvider{

@Autowired
@Qualifier("dataSource")
DataSource dataSource;

@Override
public boolean isUnwrappableAs(Class arg0) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return false;
}

@Override
public <T> T unwrap(Class<T> arg0) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return null;
}

@Override
public Connection getAnyConnection() throws SQLException {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub  
    System.out.println("=== Get any connetion === ");
    // Start 
    //BasicDataSource dataSource = new BasicDataSource();

    // End
    try {
        if(dataSource==null)
            System.out.println("dataSource null.. ");
        else
            System.out.println("dataSource not null.. ");

        System.out.println(dataSource.getConnection().createStatement().executeQuery("select 1 from dual").toString());
    } catch (Exception e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return dataSource.getConnection();
}

@Override
public Connection getConnection(String tenantId) throws SQLException {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    System.out.println("=== Get connetion === ");
    return dataSource.getConnection();
}

@Override
public void releaseAnyConnection(Connection arg0) throws SQLException {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

}

@Override
public void releaseConnection(String arg0, Connection arg1)
        throws SQLException {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

}

@Override
public boolean supportsAggressiveRelease() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return false;
}

/**
 * @return the dataSource
 */
public DataSource getDataSource() {
    return dataSource;
}

/**
 * @param dataSource the dataSource to set
 */
public void setDataSource(DataSource dataSource) {
    this.dataSource = dataSource;
}
```

}

Below is the exception i am getting, Can someone please help me to resolve this issues.

```
dataSource null.. 
java.lang.NullPointerException
at com.elecnor.ecosystem.hibernate.MultiTenantConnectionProviderImpl.getAnyConnection(MultiTenantConnectionProviderImpl.java:57)
at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.JdbcServicesImpl$MultiTenantConnectionProviderJdbcConnectionAccess.obtainConnection(JdbcServicesImpl.java:265)
at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.JdbcServicesImpl.configure(JdbcServicesImpl.java:117)
at org.hibernate.service.internal.StandardServiceRegistryImpl.configureService(StandardServiceRegistryImpl.java:76)
at org.hibernate.service.internal.AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.initializeService(AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.java:160)
at org.hibernate.service.internal.AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.getService(AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.java:132)
at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.buildTypeRegistrations(Configuration.java:1825)
at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.buildSessionFactory(Configuration.java:1783)
at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.buildSessionFactory(Configuration.java:1868)
at org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.LocalSessionFactoryBuilder.buildSessionFactory(LocalSessionFactoryBuilder.java:339)
at org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.LocalSessionFactoryBean.buildSessionFactory(LocalSessionFactoryBean.java:427)
at org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.LocalSessionFactoryBean.afterPropertiesSet(LocalSessionFactoryBean.java:412)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.invokeInitMethods(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1612)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1549)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:539)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:475)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:304)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:228)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:300)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:195)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.findAutowireCandidates(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1014)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.doResolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:957)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.resolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:855)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredFieldElement.inject(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:480)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.InjectionMetadata.inject(InjectionMetadata.java:87)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessPropertyValues(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:289)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.populateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1185)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:537)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:475)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:304)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:228)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:300)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:195)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.findAutowireCandidates(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1014)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.doResolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:957)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.resolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:855)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredFieldElement.inject(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:480)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.InjectionMetadata.inject(InjectionMetadata.java:87)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessPropertyValues(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:289)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.populateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1185)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:537)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:475)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:304)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:228)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:300)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:195)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:700)
at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:760)
at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:482)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.configureAndRefreshWebApplicationContext(FrameworkServlet.java:643)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.createWebApplicationContext(FrameworkServlet.java:606)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.createWebApplicationContext(FrameworkServlet.java:657)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.initWebApplicationContext(FrameworkServlet.java:525)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.initServletBean(FrameworkServlet.java:466)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.HttpServletBean.init(HttpServletBean.java:136)
at javax.servlet.GenericServlet.init(GenericServlet.java:158)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.initServlet(StandardWrapper.java:1284)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.loadServlet(StandardWrapper.java:1197)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.load(StandardWrapper.java:1087)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.loadOnStartup(StandardContext.java:5229)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5516)
at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1575)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1565)
at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:262)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
May 05, 2015 12:07:17 PM org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationContext log
SEVERE: StandardWrapper.Throwable
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'addressDetailsController': Injection of autowired dependencies failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Could not autowire field: com.elecnor.ecosystem.dao.AddressDetailsDAO com.elecnor.ecosystem.controller.AddressDetailsController.addressDetailsDAO; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'addressDetailsDAOImpl': Injection of autowired dependencies failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Could not autowire field: org.hibernate.SessionFactory com.elecnor.ecosystem.daoimpl.AddressDetailsDAOImpl.sessionFactory; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'sessionFactory' defined in ServletContext resource [/WEB-INF/spring-servlet.xml]: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is java.lang.NullPointerException
at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessPropertyValues(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:292)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.populateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1185)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:537)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:475)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:304)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:228)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:300)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:195)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:700)
at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:760)
at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:482)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.configureAndRefreshWebApplicationContext(FrameworkServlet.java:643)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.createWebApplicationContext(FrameworkServlet.java:606)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.createWebApplicationContext(FrameworkServlet.java:657)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.initWebApplicationContext(FrameworkServlet.java:525)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.initServletBean(FrameworkServlet.java:466)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.HttpServletBean.init(HttpServletBean.java:136)
at javax.servlet.GenericServlet.init(GenericServlet.java:158)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.initServlet(StandardWrapper.java:1284)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.loadServlet(StandardWrapper.java:1197)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.load(StandardWrapper.java:1087)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.loadOnStartup(StandardContext.java:5229)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5516)
at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1575)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1565)
at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:262)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Could not autowire field: com.elecnor.ecosystem.dao.AddressDetailsDAO com.elecnor.ecosystem.controller.AddressDetailsController.addressDetailsDAO; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'addressDetailsDAOImpl': Injection of autowired dependencies failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Could not autowire field: org.hibernate.SessionFactory com.elecnor.ecosystem.daoimpl.AddressDetailsDAOImpl.sessionFactory; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'sessionFactory' defined in ServletContext resource [/WEB-INF/spring-servlet.xml]: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is java.lang.NullPointerException
at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredFieldElement.inject(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:508)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.InjectionMetadata.inject(InjectionMetadata.java:87)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessPropertyValues(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:289)
... 29 more
```

Answer (score 2):

I dig into this issue more and found that Current Version of spring doesn't manage the multitenant implementation class that's why dataSource was not injected to the implementation class. Se the below link :- 
https://jira.spring.io/browse/SPR-10823#comment-94855

I injected the datasorce to this class using Hibernate Service registry. See the code below :- 
    public class MultiTenantConnectionProviderImpl implements MultiTenantConnectionProvider, ServiceRegistryAwareService{

```
DataSource dataSource;

@Override
public void injectServices(ServiceRegistryImplementor serviceRegistry) {
    Map lSettings = serviceRegistry.getService(ConfigurationService.class).getSettings();
    System.out.println("  ********************** " + Environment.DATASOURCE );
    System.out.println("  ********************** " + lSettings.get( Environment.DATASOURCE ) );
    dataSource = (DataSource) lSettings.get( Environment.DATASOURCE );

}

@Override
public boolean isUnwrappableAs(Class unwrapType) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return ConnectionProvider.class.equals( unwrapType ) 
            ||  MultiTenantConnectionProvider.class.equals( unwrapType ) 
            || MultiTenantConnectionProviderImpl.class.isAssignableFrom( unwrapType );
}

@Override
public <T> T unwrap(Class<T> unwrapType) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    if ( isUnwrappableAs( unwrapType ) ) {
        return (T) this;
    }
    else {
        throw new UnknownUnwrapTypeException( unwrapType );
    }
}

@Override
public Connection getAnyConnection() throws SQLException {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub  
    System.out.println("=== Get any connetion === ");
    try {
        dataSource.getConnection();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return dataSource.getConnection();
}

@Override
public Connection getConnection(String tenantId) throws SQLException {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    System.out.println("=== Get connetion === ");
    System.out.println("=== Tenant ID = "+tenantId);
    return getAnyConnection();
}

@Override
public void releaseAnyConnection(Connection connection) throws SQLException {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    System.out.println("=== releaseAnyConnection=== ");
    try {
        connection.close();
    }catch (SQLException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

}

@Override
public void releaseConnection(String tenantId, Connection connection)
        throws SQLException {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    System.out.println("=== releaseConnection=== ");
     try {
            this.releaseAnyConnection(connection);
     }catch (SQLException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

}

@Override
public boolean supportsAggressiveRelease() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    System.out.println("=== supportsAggressiveRelease=== ");
    return false;
}
```

}